# Error after installing QGIS 1.8

Tags: qgis

I have a problem with the installation of QGIS 1.8.0.

After finishing the installation two icons show on the desktop: Qgis desktop and Qgis browser.

When I click on these, it shows the same message, that `there is no file msvcr70.dll` in the computer and that it can help to reinstall the program (it didn't).

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have used the Windows standalone installer. This installer has a known bug when installing in a path with blanks, like `C:\Programs (86)\`.

Try the Osgeo4W setup, which installes to `C:\Osgeo4w` without problems.